# Copying an ArrayList that's part of a Dictionary

Tags: dictionary, arraylist, vbscript

Here is an excerpt of how my data is being created:

```
Set ds = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 
...
if ds.Exists(key) then
    if ds.item(key).count = 10 then ds.item(key).RemoveAt(0)
    ds.item(key).add(newval)
else
    Set v = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    v.add(newval)
    ds.add key,v
end if
```

Then later I'm trying to iterate through the dictionary and do some calculations on each array list.  Before doing so, I would like to copy it to a new, temporary object:

```
Set tmpAL = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
tmpAL = ds.items()(x)
```

Unfortunately this gives me the following error:

> Invalid procedure call or argument: 'tmpAL'

What is wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you could replace the two lines which are giving you a problem by the single line `Set tmpAL = ds.items()(x)` If you want to create a copy then you would need to use whatever copy method is available for arraylists.

Comment: I think that did it. Please post as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ArrayLists have a [Clone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.clone(v=vs.110).aspx) method which creates a shallow copy. The line

```
Set tmpAL = dsitems()(x).Clone()
```

should work.